# Why does my MacOS terminal ask for my password every time I start it?

Tags: macos, terminal, path, zsh, sudo

I am new to MacOS (and the world of shell), and this started happening after I tinkered with some settings while installing Homebrew. I can get out of this mode and back to the normal zsh shell using "Shift ZZ"... but it didn't ask for my password before I messed up some settings.

Here is what I see when I launch the terminal:

Header:Terminal -- sudo Last login: Fri Feb 26 22:23:31 on ttys000 /Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile:6: no such file or directory: Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile Password:

/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin

~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
"/etc/paths" 9L, 49C

And, here is what I see after I press "Shift ZZ":

Last login: Fri Feb 26 22:30:15 on ttys000 /Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile:6: no such file or directory: Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile Password: /Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile:12: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew zohaibzaheer@Zohaibs-MacBook-Air ~ %

Comment: The error message give the file where the error occorus (`.zprofile`) and the line number(s) in this file. With this, you can find the command which caused the error. Without seeing this command, nobody will be able to tell you why you have this problem. Most likely, you are trying to run something via `sudo` and are not in the list of _sudoers_.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much, but I think you might have removed the user's administrator rights.